# Audio disappears in Unity after Project Setting change

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I have a Audio Source linked to an Audio Listener looping some music. The problem with the audio is that I cannot hear anything. There are no error messages. I have tried muting the audio and then undoing it. I have also tried to restart Unity and adjusting the values on the Audio Source including pitch, volume, and looping, but the problem continues on. What is even more confusing is that when I started a project, the audio was working well, and then I did some adjusting on the Project Settings: Physics, the audio suddenly stopped. I do not have any code involved in the audio. When I tried to add another Audio Source and testing it to see if the Audio Source is the problem, it still creates no sound. I believe the problem lies nowhere near the Audio Source (though I might be wrong :D). Is there any other way to mute audio that I have missed? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without looking at the actual project it is hard to tell if it's a code issue or an environment issue. First, in editor when you click on an audio file and press the preview/play button, do you hear it? If not then it is related to unity/OS not the code.
Assuming you are running under windows, to check a few things: Kill AudioDg in task manager and Kill sihost.exe and ShellExperienceHost in task manager.

Comment: I do hear it. I'm running under Windows and I've tried your suggestions, but I think it's not something to do with the system, but the editor.

Comment: Try resetting the `Audio` Settings in Project Settings and make sure `Mute Audio` is not pressed in the game view.

Comment: Thanks. The Audio Settings worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem, just check that the Global Volume is not set to 0.  Thanks to @gameDev_Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the Global Volume Setting under Project settings > Audio and that it is not set to 0. That worked for me.

Comment: Helped by @gameDev_Unity /\ above

Comment: This site is awesome